# LibGDX Quick Button Click Action

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx

I'm new to LibGDX. One issue I'm running into is having buttons reacting with each other when they're pressed. For example, in my code below, when I press one of these buttons, I want the other two to automatically be unpressed (only one of the three buttons can be in it's pressed state at a time). The issue I'm running into is that there seems to be quite a bit of delay for the buttons to switch states.

```
public MenuStateTest(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    fitViewport = new FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();

    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttonTest.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("1BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T1BBlock");
    button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.setPosition(20, 200);
    button.getStyle().checked = button.getStyle().down;
    button.setChecked(false);


        button2Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button2Test.pack");
        skin.addRegions(button2Atlas);
        textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("2BBlock");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T2BBlock");
        button2 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
        stage.addActor(button2);
        button2.setPosition(175, 200);
        button2.getStyle().checked = button2.getStyle().down;
        button2.setChecked(true);

        button3Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button3Test.pack");
        skin.addRegions(button3Atlas);
        textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("3BBlock");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T3BBlock");
        button3 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
        stage.addActor(button3);
        button3.setPosition(330, 200);
        button3.getStyle().checked = button3.getStyle().down;
        button3.setChecked(true);

}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {
    if(button.isChecked()&& button.isPressed()){
        button.setChecked(false);
        button2.setChecked(true);
        button3.setChecked(true);
    }

    if(button2.isChecked()&& button2.isPressed()){
        button.setChecked(true);
        button2.setChecked(false);
        button3.setChecked(true);
    }

    if(button3.isChecked()&& button3.isPressed()){
        button.setChecked(true);
        button2.setChecked(true);
        button3.setChecked(false);
    }


}

@Override
protected void update(float dt) {
    stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    handleInput();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure...do you understand that "pressed' means the finger is still being held down on the button? A button's checked state toggles when it's "clicked" which means it was pressed and then released with the same finger still over the button. And is your goal to have three toggle-buttons? There's already a ButtonGroup class available for handling radio button functionality.

Comment: So, all I'd have to do is to add the buttons above to a ButtonGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public MenuStateTest(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    fitViewport = new FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();

    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttonTest.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("1BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T1BBlock");
    button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.setPosition(20, 200);

    button2Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button2Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button2Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("2BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T2BBlock");
    button2 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button2);
    button2.setPosition(175, 200);

    button3Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button3Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button3Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("3BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T3BBlock");
    button3 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button3);
    button3.setPosition(330, 200);

    ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup(button1, button2, button3);
    buttons.setMaxCheckCount(1);
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {

}

@Override
protected void update(float dt) {
    stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: This is a start in the right direction for me. However, I'm still unaware of how this class works, as I'm learning as I go along. One problem I'm running into is that even with seMaxCheckCount set to one, I can still have all three buttons checked if my fingers are on them at the same time. Reading the API, I don't see anyway how I can make sure only one button stays down regardless if my other fingers are on the other buttons.

Ideally I want this: One finger is on button1 and stays there as my other finger touches button2/3, then I want button1 to go back up and button2/3 to go down.

Comment: Your down and checked states looked the same. I edited the answer, try the code now. If it works, compare it to your own - that's the best way to learn :-)

Comment: It's almost there to what I want :P
One thing I'm trying to figure out is how to make it so that only one of the buttons can be in its down state at a time. The problem for your current method is that the button changes state when I let go of my finger. Are there any new classes I have to use? Or could I mess around with the current methods in the TextButton and ButtonGroup classes?